# Explicit isomorphism $\Lambda^2\Lambda^2V\oplus\Lambda^4V\cong V\otimes\Lambda^3V$

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, representation-theory, exterior-algebra, lambda-rings

I remember some years ago reading about "lambda rings" learning there are some relations between exterior powers and their combinations. The smallest example of such a relation was $\Lambda^2\Lambda^2V\oplus\Lambda^4V\cong V\otimes\Lambda^3V$ (and there was another involving I think $\Lambda^2(V\otimes W)$ but I don't remember what it was). Checking characters I verified these must be equivalent representations of $\mathrm{GL}(V)$, so in other words $\Lambda^2\Lambda^2\oplus\Lambda^4$ must be "naturally isomorphic" to $\mathrm{Id}\otimes\Lambda^3$.

What is such a natural isomorphism, explicitly?

The first thing that came to mind was to examine the "decategorified" situation. An ordered basis $\{v_i\}$ for $V$ lends to ordered bases for these reps, and if the natural isomorphism sends such bases for the one rep into such bases for the other (an optimistic guess), then the basis ought to be equivalent as $S_n$-sets (where $n=\dim V$). To this end:

- $\Lambda^4V$ (irrep) has an ordered basis $\{v_i\wedge w_j\wedge v_k\wedge v_l\mid {\small i<j<k<l}\}$
- $\Lambda^2\Lambda^2V$ has an ordered basis consisting of two parts: $$\{(v_i\wedge v_j)\wedge(v_k\wedge v_l)\mid {\small i<j<k<l}\} \\ \sqcup \\ \{(v_i\wedge v_j)\wedge(v_i\wedge v_k)\mid {\small j<k;\, i\not\int\{j,k\}}\}$$
- $V\otimes\Lambda^3V$ has an ordered basis consisting of two parts: $$\{v_i\otimes(v_j\wedge v_k\wedge v_l)\mid {\small j<k<l;\,i\not\in\{j,k,l\}}\} \\ \sqcup \\ \{v_i\otimes(v_i\wedge v_j\wedge v_k)\mid {\small j<k;\, i\not\in\{j,k\}}\} $$

These reveal that, as $S_n$-sets, one basis has $3$ orbits while the other has $2$, so a natural isomorphism must combine these basis vectors into mixtures somehow.

I'd be fine with a natural isomorphism that takes for granted $V$ is an inner product space. (A mere vector space isomorphism is just a simple combinatorics exercise so that wouldn't cut it.)

[Also, any direct reference to more of these relations and how to generate them, with the least amount of literature-brushing-up as a prerequisite?]

[I'd also be curious if $\binom{\binom{n}{2}}{2}+\binom{n}{4}-n\binom{n}{3}$, suitably interpreted as a virtual $S_n$-set, has a special place in the Burnside ring of $S_n$, or maybe the ideal generated by all lambda relations has some special description, or whatever.]

Comment: There is a canonical surjective map of $GL(V)$-modules $p: W:=V\otimes \wedge^3 V \rightarrow \wedge^4 V$, and you must construct a splitting $s$ of this map. One obvious map is $s(v_1\wedge \cdots \wedge v_4):= \frac{1}{4}\sum_i (-1)^{i+1}v_i\otimes v(i)$ where $v(i)$ leaves out the $v_i$-term. If this is well defined it splits $p$ and gives a direct sum decomposition $W \cong ker(p)\oplus \wedge^4 V$.

Comment: it seems the map s is well defined and a map of $GL(V)$-modules, hence $W≅ker(p)⊕∧^4V$. It remains to determine $ker(p)$.

Comment: "hopefully you see what I mean" - you should write down this basis in the thread. Such a description should give a $GL(V)$-invariant map $\wedge^2(\wedge^2 V) \rightarrow V \otimes \wedge^3 V$, identifying $ker(p)$.

Comment: Note that $\wedge^2(\wedge^k V)$ is reducible (not irreducible) in general.

Comment: @hm2020 I basically already gave the bases I was talking about originally, when I said "elements of the form [...]," but I've edited to make it more explicit. Indeed I recognize the two $S_n$-orbits in the basis of $\Lambda^2\Lambda^2V$ correspond to two $GL(V)$-subirreps. However, I don't see how the bases' explicit description gives a way to identify $\Lambda^2\Lambda^2V$ with the kernel of $V\otimes\Lambda^3V\to\Lambda^4V$.

Comment: For $SL(V)$ ($dim(V)=n+1$) there is always a perfect pairing $V\otimes \wedge^nV \rightarrow \wedge^{n+1}V\cong det(V) \cong Triv$, hence $\wedge^n V\cong V^*$ and $V\otimes \wedge^n V \cong V^*\otimes V \cong \mathfrak{gl}(V)$. This has $\mathfrak{sl}(V)$ as a sub module. Maybe this is useful.

Comment: A comment: let $V$ be a vector space of dimension at least 4. Then $V \otimes \Lambda^3 V \cong \Lambda^4 V \oplus S^{(2, 1, 1)} V$ (call that isomorphism (X)) as $\operatorname{GL}(V)$-representations, where $S^{(2, 1, 1)} V$ denotes the Schur functor/module associated to the partition $(2, 1, 1)$. So one could perhaps state your problem as understanding (a) the isomorphism (X), (b) the Schur module $S^{(2, 1, 1)}$, (c) the plethysm $\Lambda^2 \Lambda^2 V$, and finally (d) the isomorphism $\Lambda^2 \Lambda^2 V \cong S^{(2, 1, 1)}V$.

Comment: I believe I found an explicit isomorphism, defined by $(v_i\wedge v_j)\wedge(v_k\wedge v_l) \mapsto \frac12 (v_i\otimes(v_j\wedge v_k\wedge v_l)-v_j\otimes(v_i\wedge v_k\wedge v_l)-v_k\otimes(v_i\wedge v_j\wedge v_l)+v_l\otimes(v_i\wedge v_j\wedge v_k))$ (for any $i,j,k,l$, not necessarily distinct), plus the obvious $v_i\wedge v_j\wedge v_k\wedge v_l \mapsto \frac12 (v_i\otimes(v_j\wedge v_k\wedge v_l)-v_j\otimes(v_i\wedge v_k\wedge v_l)+v_k\otimes(v_i\wedge v_j\wedge v_l)-v_l\otimes(v_i\wedge v_j\wedge v_k))$. If I got the constants right, the map should also be an isometry.